# Azure function : HttpTrigger and output queue returned "Internal Server Error"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have the following code of function:

```
public static class FunctionCheckEmail
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionCheckEmail")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [Queue("email-message-admin-confirmation", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]CloudQueue outputQueue,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return new AcceptedResult();
    }
}
```

It returned `Internal Server Error`.

If I remove Queue binding then it works:

```
public static class FunctionCheckEmail
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionCheckEmail")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return new AcceptedResult();
    }
}
```

Other function with Queue binding works fine:

```
public static class FunctionWarningNotification
{
    [FunctionName("FunctionWarningNotification")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("emails-warning-notification", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")]string myQueueItem,
        [SendGrid] out SendGridMessage message,
        ExecutionContext context,
        ILogger log)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSendGridApiKey": "XXXX",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "StorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=domainregistration;AccountKey=XXXX"
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of the problem - nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage (ver 9.3.3), pulled to my Azure App with dependency project, breaks this bindings

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT can do it only tomorrow. P.S. as I understand, it's a bug of WindowsAzure.Storage package (or Azure WebJobs Sdk)

Comment: Will check with the azure storage team to see if they have any release planned for that.

Comment: Fow now, you do [need to use 9.3.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3784).